# No OpenGL context when using SDL2 on Mac OS X 10.8.4

Tags: c, opengl, sdl

On Mac OS X 10.8.4, the following program behaves as if no OpenGL context is associated with the window.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_opengl.h>

static void render( void );
static void gl_info( void );
static void dump_sdl_error( void );

SDL_Window* window = NULL;
SDL_GLContext ctx = NULL;

GLuint program = 0;
GLint attribute_vertex = 0;
GLint attribute_color = 0;


int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    if( SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0 )
    {
        goto quit;
    }

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3 );
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 2 );
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE );

    window = SDL_CreateWindow( "Test Shaders", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );

    if( window == NULL )
    {
        dump_sdl_error( );
        goto quit;
    }

    ctx = SDL_GL_CreateContext( window );

    if( !ctx )
    {
        dump_sdl_error( );
        goto quit;
    }

    dump_sdl_error( );

    gl_info( );


    render( );

quit:
    if( ctx ) SDL_GL_DeleteContext( ctx );
    if( window ) SDL_DestroyWindow( window );
    SDL_Quit( );
    return 0;
}


void render( )
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT );
    glClearColor( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );

    SDL_GL_SwapWindow( window );
}

void gl_info( void )
{
    const char* renderer     = (const char*) glGetString(GL_RENDERER);
    const char* version      = (const char*) glGetString(GL_VERSION);
    const char* glsl_version = (const char*) glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION);

    fprintf( stdout, "[GL] Renderer: %s\n", renderer ? renderer : "unknown" );
    fprintf( stdout, "[GL] Version: %s\n", version ? version : "unknown" );
    fprintf( stdout, "[GL] Shading Language: %s\n", glsl_version ? glsl_version : "unknown" );
}


void dump_sdl_error( void )
{
    const char* sdl_error = SDL_GetError( );

    if( sdl_error && *sdl_error != '\0' )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "[SDL] %s\n", sdl_error );
    }
}
```

The above program produces the following output:

```
$ ./bin/test-shaders 
[GL] Renderer: unknown
[GL] Version: unknown
[GL] Shading Language: unknown
```

It seems like I have no context but I'm at a lost.  I'm expecting to see the GLSL version and my graphics hardware shown, but it appears that glGetString() returns NULL. Any SDL2 experts out there?

Comment: Hi Andon.  I considered that and have tried calling SDL_GL_MakeCurrent().  The header file also has a comment that SDL_GL_CreateContext() makes the context current after creating it. This may be an SDL bug on Mac OS X.

Comment: Can you include the command you are using to build this? I came across a similar question on SO where failing to include the framework cocoa would lead to a failure to create the render context. glfw and SDL have both migrated to NSOpenGL recently (based on Cocoa/Obj-C) since the old CGL/AGL API (based on Carbon/C) is slowly being phased out in modern OS X. This can lead to compatibility issues when upgrading projects, the good news is all you usually have to do is include the proper framework and ignore the fact that part of your program is sitting on top of Obj-C :)

Comment: Thanks buddy.  I just solved it before you commented.  What's bizarre is that the context pointer is not NULL so it looks like I have a context but no GL functions work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.  Apparently, the code will still compile if you're missing "-framework OpenGL"

I solved this by examining the test programs that came with SDL2 and found that they did indeed work and that I was missing the framework OpenGL.  I hope this helps someone else.

Thank you Andon.

I changed this:

```
__top_builddir__bin_test_sdl_SOURCES = test-sdl.c
__top_builddir__bin_test_sdl_LDFLAGS = -lGL -lSDL2 $(top_builddir)/lib/.libs/libsimplegl.a
```

To this:

```
__top_builddir__bin_test_sdl_SOURCES = test-sdl.c
__top_builddir__bin_test_sdl_LDFLAGS = -lGL -lSDL2 -framework OpenGL $(top_builddir)/lib/.libs/libsimplegl.a
```